# How can I find the amount of seconds passed from the midnight with Java?

Tags: java, time

I need a function that gives me how many seconds passed from the midnight. I am currently using `System.currentTimeMillis()` but it gives me the UNIX like timestamp.

It would be a bonus for me if I could get the milliseconds too.

Comment: Which time zone? The current default time zone, UTC, or some other time zone?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you're using Java >= 8, this is easily done :

```
ZonedDateTime nowZoned = ZonedDateTime.now();
Instant midnight = nowZoned.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(nowZoned.getZone()).toInstant();
Duration duration = Duration.between(midnight, Instant.now());
long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
```

If you're using Java 7 or less, you have to get the date from midnight via Calendar, and then substract.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
long now = c.getTimeInMillis();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long passed = now - c.getTimeInMillis();
long secondsPassed = passed / 1000;
```

Comment: Great answer, the first one suits better for me. Thank you.

Comment: If ever there were an API that needed to be immutable and assembled with Builder objects, it would be the Java SE Calendar/Date API.  I can't begin to imagine what they were thinking.

Comment: That first one returns the time in *milliseconds* not seconds. But I'm sure everyone realises that :-)

Comment: You could also edit your answer to account for the fact that `DateMidnight` is deprecated now :)

Comment: FYI, both `Calendar` and Joda-Time are now outmoded. (a) The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. (b) The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque added the Java8 answer to be proper

Comment: If using Java 6 or Java 7, they should be using the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project to access much of the java.time functionality. Never use `Calendar`/`Date`. No need, and those legacy classes are an awful mess.

Comment: Your edits for using *java.time* are better, but (a) avoid the amorphous concept of “midnight”, (b) truncating to `DAYS` works, but seems clumsier that asking *java.time* to determine the first moment of the day with a call to `atStartOfDay` as seen in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34822517/642706). To be clear, days do *not* always start at 00:00:00.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm using midnight because the'yre using that precise term in the question. I agree about atStartOfDay however, I'll modify it

Comment: `java.time.ZonedDateTime` doesn't have the methode `atStartOfDay()` as your answer suggests. `java.time.LocalDate` has it.

Comment: I'm gonna edit this answer to keep ZonedDateTime (in order to benefit from the zone info), but make it compile properly (and using some answers from @BasilBourque)

Comment: I suggest you avoid the “midnight” terminology as it is ambiguous and confusing. If you mean first moment of the day, say so precisely with phrasing like “first moment of day” or “start of day”.

Answer (score 14):

## java.time

Using the [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

```
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.ZoneId

LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()) // LocalTime = 14:42:43.062
now.toSecondOfDay() // Int = 52963
```

It is good practice to explicit specify `ZoneId`, even if you want default one.

Comment: This approach is not specific. `LocalTime` represents a time-of-day *in general*. This class knows only of generic 24-hours days. Lacking the details of a specific time zone, this class cannot know anything about anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). For example, in the United States, DST means a day can be 23, 24, or 25 hours long. So, in the US, the span of time until midnight can vary by ± 1 hour from one day to another.

Answer (score 12):

## tl;dr

“Midnight” is a fuzzy term, best left unsaid. Focus on the first moment of the day.

Capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Calculate the time elapsed since the first moment of the day by calling [`ZonedDateTime::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#get(java.time.temporal.TemporalField)) and passing a [`ChronoField`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html) enum object.

Whole [seconds](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#SECOND_OF_DAY).

```
int secondOfDay = zdt.get( ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY ) ;
```

[Milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#MILLI_OF_DAY).

```
int milliOfDay = zdt.get( ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY ) ;
```

[Microseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#MICRO_OF_DAY).

```
int microOfDay = zdt.get( ChronoField.MICRO_OF_DAY ) ;
```

[Nanoseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#NANO_OF_DAY).

```
int nanoOfDay = zdt.get( ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY ) ;
```

Determine first moment of the day.

Be aware that the day does not always start at 00:00:00. Some dates in some time zones may start at another time-of-day such as 01:00:00. Always let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day with `atStartOfDay` method.

```
Instant then =                             // Represent a moment in UTC.
    ZonedDateTime                          // Represent a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    .now(                                  // Capture the current moment. Holds up to nanosecond resolution, but current hardware computer clocks limited to microseconds for telling current time.
        ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" )   // Specify the time zone. Never use 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `IST`, `PST`, `EST`.
    )                                      // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toLocalDate()                         // Extract the date-only portion, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    .atStartOfDay(                         // Deterimine the first moment of the day on that date in that time zone. Beware: The day does *not* always begin at 00:00:00.
        ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" )   // Specify the time zone for which we want the first moment of the day on that date.
    )                                      // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toInstant()                           // Adjusts from that time zone to UTC. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
;
```

Represent time elapsed as a `Duration`, a span-of-time unattached from the timeline.

```
Duration                                   // Represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline in terms of hours-minutes-seconds.
.between(                                  // Specify start and stop moments.
    then ,                                 // Calculated in code seen above.
    Instant.now()                          // Capture current moment in UTC. 
)                                          // Returns a `Duration` object.
.getSeconds()                              // Extract the total number of whole seconds accross this entire span-of-time.
```

## java.time

Java 8 and later has the java.time framework baked in.

By using `ZonedDateTime` and time zone, we are handling anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). For example, in the United States **a day can be 23, 24, or 25 hours** long. So the time until tomorrow can vary by ±1 hour from one day to another.

First get the current moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

Now extract the date-only portion, a `LocalDate`, and use that date to ask java.time when that day began for our desired time zone. Do not assume the day began at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean that the day may begin at another time such as 01:00:00.

```
ZonedDateTime todayStart = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( z );  // Crucial to specify our desired time zone!
```

Now we can get the delta between the current moment and the start of today. Such a span of time unattached to the timeline is represented by the `Duration` class.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( todayStart , now );
```

Ask the `Duration` object for the total number of seconds in the entire span of time.

```
long secondsSoFarToday = duration.getSeconds();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and fastest method to get the seconds since midnight for the current timezone:

One-time setup:

```
static final long utcOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

If you use Apache Commons, you can use DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, otherwise  define:

```
static final long DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

And then, whenever you need the time...:

```
int seconds = (int)((System.currentTimeMillis() + utcOffset) % DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS / 1000);
```

Note that you'll need to re-setup if there's a possibility that your program will run long enough, and Daylight Saving Times change occurs...

Comment: You can use the `DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS` constant rather than calculating it.

Comment: @BillMote, DateUtils only available if you use Apache Commons. Edited that as an option...

Comment: Good point.  Didn't consider that, but I do like the readability.

Comment: This is actually the best answer, as it is the most performance-efficient

Answer (score 1):

Using JodaTime you can call:

```
int seconds = DateTime.now().secondOfDay().get();
int millis = DateTime.now().millisOfDay().get();
```

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque OK, where is `millisOfDay` in `java.time` then?

Comment: @izogfif See the top of [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34822517/642706). `ZonedDateTime::get( ChronoField )`

Answer (score 1):

Use getTime().getTime() instead of getTimeInMillis() if you get an error about calendar being protected.  Remember your imports:

```
import java.util.*;
```

will include them all while you are debugging:

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar midnight = Calendar.getInstance();
    midnight.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    midnight.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    midnight.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    midnight.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    long ms = now.getTime().getTime() - midnight.getTime().getTime();
    totalMinutesSinceMidnight = (int) (ms / 1000 / 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) % (24 * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: This will give you the number of seconds since the beginning of the last day in UTC, not the local timezone.

Comment: Of course it will work with DST transitions.  The number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight do not change when a DST transition occurs; only the local time changes.

Answer (score 0):

Like @secmask, if you need milli-seconds since GMT midnight, try

```
long millisSinceGMTMidnight = System.currentTimeMillis() % (24*60*60*1000);
```