# Get milliseconds until midnight

Tags: java, android, date, milliseconds

I'm creating an Android widget that I want to update every night at midnight. I am using an `AlarmManager` and I need to find out how many milliseconds are left from the current time until midnight. Here's my code:

```
AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, millisecondsUntilMidnight, mSrvcPendingingIntent);
```

How can I calculate how many milliseconds are left until midnight?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This might help, just flip it around in your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389500/how-can-i-find-the-amount-of-seconds-passed-from-the-midnight-with-java

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use a Calendar to compute it :

```
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long howMany = (c.getTimeInMillis()-System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: You should be sure to use Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY and not Calendar.HOUR, because Calendar.HOUR is based on a 12-hour clock.  Your midnight calculation might be wrong, depending on what time of day you run the code.  I found this out by observation.

Comment: [`Calendar.getInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29) is already set to the current date&time, so `c.setTime(now)` is unnecessary. You can also use [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) to compare with your calendar value

Comment: Hi does your solution require wake lock methods in onReceive method? This: PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Whatever/any tag"); //Acquire the lock wl.acquire(); Log.d("widget", "in alarm manager. static method will come next"); //Release the lock wl.release();

Comment: This will fail on last day of month, you should use add(Calendar.DATE, 1) not DAY_OF_MONTH

Comment: @GregEnnis no it won't. Calendar implementation do exactly the same thing for DATE, DAY_OF_MONTH, DAY_OF_YEAR and DAY_OF_WEEK in ̀add` (you can check the sources).

Comment: I want to get percentage, but seems System.currentTimeMillis()/c.getTimeInMillis() always give 0.9999....
Dont understand why....

Answer (score 25):

## tl;dr

```java
java.time.Duration
.between( now , tomorrowStart )
.toMillis()
```

## java.time

Java 8 and later comes with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built-in. These new classes supplant the old date-time classes (java.util.Date/.Calendar) bundled with Java. Also supplants Joda-Time, developed by the same people. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7, and further adapted to Android (see below).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

We want to get the number of milliseconds running up to, but not including, the first moment of the next day.

We must go through the `LocalDate` class to get at the first moment of a day. So here we start with a `ZonedDateTime` to get a `LocalDate`, and after that get another `ZonedDateTime`. The key is calling [`atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) on the `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = now.toLocalDate().plusDays(1);
ZonedDateTime tomorrowStart = tomorrow.atStartOfDay( z );
```

Notice that we do not hard-code a time-of-day at 00:00:00. Because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST), the day does may start at another time such as 01:00:00. Let java.time determine the first moment.

Now we can calculate elapsed time. In java.time we use the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class. The java.time framework has a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than the coarser milliseconds used by both java.util.Date and Joda-Time. But `Duration` includes a handy [`getMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis--) method, as the Question requested.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( now , tomorrowStart );
long millisecondsUntilTomorrow = duration.toMillis();
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/CfocGj).

> now.toString(): 2017-05-02T12:13:59.379-04:00[America/Montreal]

> tomorrowStart.toString(): 2017-05-03T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

> millisecondsUntilTomorrow: 42360621

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. I leave this section intact for the sake of history, but recommend using java.time and ThreeTenABP as discussed above.

In Android you should be using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library rather than the notoriously troublesome Java.util.Date/.Calendar classes.

Joda-Time offers a [milliseconds-of-day command](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#millisOfDay()). But we don't really need that here.

Instead we just need a [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) object to represent the span of time until first moment of next day.

Time zone is critical here to determine when "tomorrow" starts. Generally better to specify than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone which can change at any moment. Or if you really want the JVM’s default, ask for that explicitly with call to [`DateTimeZone.getDefault`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getDefault()) to make your code self-documenting.

Could be a two-liner.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
long milliSecondsUntilTomorrow = new Duration( now , now.plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay() ).getMillis();
```

Let's take that apart.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ); // Or, DateTimeZone.getDefault()
DateTime now = DateTime.now( zone );
DateTime tomorrow = now.plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();  // FYI the day does not *always* start at 00:00:00.0 time.
Duration untilTomorrow = new Duration( now , tomorrow );
long millisecondsUntilTomorrow = untilTomorrow.getMillis();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "From now : " + now + " until tomorrow : " + tomorrow + " is " + millisecondsUntilTomorrow + " ms." );
```

When run.

> From now : 2015-09-20T19:45:43.432-04:00 until tomorrow : 2015-09-21T00:00:00.000-04:00 is 15256568 ms.

Comment: You get a big'ol rock on for the java 8 implementation. I had been looking for that for a while. Thank you very much. BTW you should break your answer into a separate answer because it is a little harder to find when the title is Joda. Even though the java 8 spec is very similar.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw I revamped this Answer per your suggestion. Moved java.time info up top, marked the Joda-Time section as outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
long now = c.getTimeInMillis();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

long millisecondsUntilMidnight = c.getTimeInMillis() - now;

AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, millisecondsUntilMidnight, mSrvcPendingingIntent);
```

Comment: (c.getTimeInMillis - now) will be negative?

Comment: This computes the time to **last** midnight. You must increment the day (see my answer).

Comment: I've edited my answer (incremented the day by one). Thanks for warnings.

Comment: The Documentation shows "SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000" to set the alarm with AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME to one minute in the future. So shouldnt it be "SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + millisecondsUntilMidnight" in ur example?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
long MILLIS_IN_DAY = 86400000;

long currentTime = System.currentTimeInMillis();

long millisTillNow = currentTime % MILLIS_IN_DAY;

long millisecondsUntilMidnight = MILLIS_IN_DAY - millisTillNow;
```

Comment: Hum. I don't think this deals with reality (spare seconds, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`AlarmManager.RTC`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC) instead of `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME`, and just set a Calendar to the time you want :

```
// Create a calendar for midnight
Calendar todayMidnight = Calendar.getInstance();
todayMidnight.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
todayMidnight.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
todayMidnight.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
todayMidnight.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

// Create an alarm going off at midnight
mAlarmManager.set(
   AlarmManager.RTC, 
   todayMidnight.getTimeInMillis(), 
   mSrvcPendingingIntent
);
```

Comment: Hi does your solution require wake lock methods in onReceive method? This: PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Whatever/any tag");
        //Acquire the lock
        wl.acquire();

        Log.d("widget", "in alarm manager. static method will come next");

        //Release the lock
        wl.release();

Comment: From the documentation: "The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm receiver's onReceive() method is executing". So you do not need to handle the wake lock yourself.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: How did you do it? Could I have a code snippets? I assume it would be similar for all cases.

Comment: How did I do what ? I have feeling you might be better served by creating your own question on Stack Overflow, comments are not really up to the task

Comment: My Alarm Manager doesn't update my widget even with wake lock in onReceive: PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "widgetWL");
wakeLock.acquire();
wakeLock.release()

Answer (score 0):

Using the following way, there is no need to worry about setting DAY_OF_MONTH.

```
    long msInDay = 86400000;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    System.out.print(msInDay - (System.currentTimeMillis() - c.getTimeInMillis()));
```