# How can I call a function every day at 00:00 in my web service

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, rest

My problem is that I have a RESTful Web Service using a class `Gestion`.
In this class, I have a function `_update_`, and I would like to call this function everyday at 00:00.

I had no idea how to do that, so I looked into the Web, and I found that using threads might be a good option. However, I don't know how I can use it. Do I have to move my `_update_` function into a new class ?

Comment: wich language, versions, etc. are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, I totally forgot to mention that.
I'm using Java, with Jersey 2, on a Tomcat 7.0 Servlet Container.

Comment: Use a cron job library like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

Comment: Why not just good old `cron`?

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using EJB** you can use the timer service

```
@Singleton
public class TimerService {
    @Inject
    HelloService helloService;

    @Schedule(second="0", minute="0", hour="0")
    public void update(){
        System.out.println("timer: " + helloService.sayHello());
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples004.htm

Comment: Sadly, I'm not using EJB. :(
I'm still gonna try and see how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use any open source job or schedulers more details are here. http://toppersworld.com/top-10-open-source-java-job-schedulers/
Or do pure coding. This link may help you.  [Get milliseconds until midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989555/get-milliseconds-until-midnight). Sleep until midnight in a thread and wake up do task and go and sleep again.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(calculateSleepingTime());
            // do what ever you want
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private long calculateSleepingTime() throws ParseException {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return (c.getTimeInMillis()-System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```