# Calulating the time difference in minutes and seconds

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

How can i subtract from two timestamps (i need to concentrate only time diffeerence not dates)

one is attendedInTime and other is plannedInTime, and these two times are in timestamp.

I have written following query it is not working some scenario's.

```
SELECT (
   TO_NUMBER(substr(to_Char(attendedintime,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 12, 2) ) -  
   TO_NUMBER(substr(to_Char(plannedInTime, 'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 12, 2) )
  ) 
   || ':' || 
 ( 
   TO_NUMBER(substr(to_Char(attendedintime,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 15, 2) ) - 
   TO_NUMBER(substr(to_Char(plannedInTime, 'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 15, 2) )
 ) AS difference FROM TABLENAME
```

But as per the above query i am not able syncup with the hours and minutes
(It is calclating differently minutes and hours)

Comment: Could you please sort out your tags?  EITHER you want to know how to do this in Java, OR you want to know how to do it in Oracle/SQL.  Tagging it with all three just seems greedy.

Comment: If you want away to do this in Java, you could take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974729/how-to-get-the-time-since-midnight-in-seconds/18975189#18975189)

Comment: @David, I have updated my question as well as tags

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I want to do operation in oracle database

Answer (score 1):

Assuming attendedInTime > plannedInTime:

```
select extract (hour from (attendedInTime - plannedInTime)) as HOUR_DIFF,
       extract (minute from (attendedInTime - plannedInTime)) as MINUTE_DIFF, 
       extract (second from (attendedInTime - plannedInTime)) as SECOND_DIFF
  from tab ;
```

Comment: I am getting this errorORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source 30076. 00000 - "invalid extract field for extract source" *Cause: The extract source does not contain the specified extract field

Comment: What is the result of qwery `select attendedInTime - plannedInTime from tab` ? If its a number then the datatypes are not timestamps.

Comment: attendedInTime, plannedInTime columns data type is Date in database.
In Database column values having both Date with time. Now i am trying to differentiate only time.

Comment: select
to_Char(attendedintime,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') as InTime,
to_Char(plannedintime,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') as OutTime,
substr(to_Char(attendedintime,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 12, 9) AS abc,
substr(to_Char(plannedintime,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 12, 9) AS xyz
from TABLENAME
THEN OUT PUT AS FOLLOWS :-
01.11.2013:06:09:00 01.01.1970:08:30:00 06:09:00 08:30:00


Here i need difference between in "06:09:00" And "08:30:00
" AS hours:min:sec

Comment: Then use `select extract (hour from (attendedInTime - plannedInTime))||':'|| extract (minute from (attendedInTime - plannedInTime))||':'|| extract (second from (attendedInTime - plannedInTime)) as TIME_DIFF from tab;` If plannedInTime > attendedInTime  then change `(attendedInTime - plannedInTime)` to `(plannedInTime - attendedInTime )`

Comment: Thanks for your comment here attendedInTime/plannedInTime is combined with date+time, first i need to extract the time only from the database value . After that i need to get the difference of the both times.

Comment: I have written following query it is not working some scenario's.
SELECT
(TO_NUMBER(substr(to_Char(attendedintime,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 12, 2) ) - TO_NUMBER(substr(to_Char(plannedInTime,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 12, 2)  )) || ':' || 
(TO_NUMBER(substr(to_Char(attendedintime,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 15, 2)  ) - TO_NUMBER(substr(to_Char(plannedInTime,'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 15, 2)  )) AS difference
from TABLENAME

But as per the above query i am not able syncup with the hours and minutes.