# Timestamp for only time

Tags: timestamp

Is there any standard equivalent of timestamp for time only?
The unix time stamp is merely the number of seconds between a particular date and the Unix Epoch, Is there any similar standard for time (hours-minutes-seconds) only?

Comment: [ISO 8601-1:2019 Date and time — Representations for information interchange](https://www.iso.org/standard/70907.html)

Comment: in which context do you need this? there's [seconds since midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974729/how-to-get-the-time-since-midnight-in-seconds) for example