# Java (Joda): Seconds from midnight of LocalDateTime

Tags: java, time, jodatime

I tried to use this:

```
secondsFromMidnight = Seconds.secondsBetween(localDateTime.toLocalDate(),    
    localDateTime).getSeconds();
```

but it throws an exception (cf. below). I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389500/how-can-i-find-the-amount-of-seconds-passed-from-the-midnight-with-java) is a good approach, but I did not succeed in adapt it to my case yet. If I write this:

```
    DateTime dateTimeFromMidnight = new DateMidnight(localDateTime.getChronology()).toDateTime();
    Duration duration = new Duration(dateTimeFromMidnight, localDateTime.toDateTime());
```

it messes up with time zones (I get 1 hour less).

If your solution is also easily adaptable for hours, minutes and so on, that's a plus.

I need absolutely to use LocalDateTime as input type, please do not post solutions with other classes.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ReadablePartial objects must have the same set of fields
at org.joda.time.base.BaseSingleFieldPeriod.between(BaseSingleFieldPeriod.java:92)
at org.joda.time.Seconds.secondsBetween(Seconds.java:124)
```

Comment: what exception? can you post it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to know the time of day, in seconds since midnight, it would be easiest to just use [`getMillisOfDay()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#getMillisOfDay%28%29):

```
int secondsOfDay = localDateTime.getMillisOfDay() / 1000;
```

(Use `DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_SECOND` if you really want to - in this case I think the knowledge of "1000 milliseconds per second" is easy enough.)

You can use the same approach for minutes and hours, of course.

If you really want it as a period, you could use `LocalDateTime.withMillisOfDay(0)` to obtain a `LocalDateTime` at midnight of the same day, e.g.

```
secondsFromMidnight = Seconds.secondsBetween(localDateTime.withMillisOfDay(0), 
                                             localDateTime)
                             .getSeconds();
```

... but personally I'd probably just use `getMillisOfDay`.