# Retrieving data from database and converting

Tags: java

How do I create a method that retrieve a column of data from database with different values (e.g. 20040804142000, 20040805034000)?

The values are YYYYMMDDHHMMSS and I am suppose to convert them into minutes from 12am. Is there any method to convert all of the data I would require and implement it into my statement.

e.g. output would be

20040805034000 > 220

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` will allow you to convert the `String` value to a `Date`...

Comment: @Satya  as for what i've tried, I am trying to use a set of codes from what I found in this website for the conversion. For the retrieval part is mainly where I can't seem to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [date format and converting that date to JodaTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324149/date-format-and-converting-that-date-to-jodatime)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8

So, start with [How to parse/format dates with LocalDateTime? (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) you can convert a `String` value to a `LocalDateTime` using something like...

```
String value = "20040805034000";
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(value, format);
System.out.println(ldt);
```

Which outputs `2004-08-5T03:40`.

Next you can use `ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between` to calculate the number of seconds between two times, but this means you need an anchor time, which would be midnight in your case...

```
LocalDateTime midnight = ldt.withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(midnight, ldt);
System.out.println(seconds);
```

Which outputs `13200`

## [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

If you can't use Java 8, then use Joda-Time instead.  So starting with [Converting a date string to a DateTime object using Joda Time library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252678/converting-a-date-string-to-a-datetime-object-using-joda-time-library) and [Java (Joda): Seconds from midnight of LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622332/java-joda-seconds-from-midnight-of-localdatetime)

```
String value = "20040805034000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
LocalDateTime dt = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(value);
System.out.println(dt);

LocalDateTime midnight = dt.withMillisOfDay(0);

long seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(midnight, dt).getSeconds();
System.out.println(seconds);
```

Comment: it is true also for Java 7 and 6

Comment: @igreen Yep, that's why I put the Joda-Time example in :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using libraries like joda-time for this. If you want a more rudimentary answer you could try this:

```
public int getMinutesSinceMidnight(String s){
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8,10));
    int mins = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(10,12));
    return hour*60+mins;
{
```

Comment: For the retrieval part you would need to give us more details about the database.

Comment: @trunite the table name is clockIn, the column name that I would like to retrieve is called dateTime