# How to convert "hh mm a" format string to seconds in java

Tags: java, datetime, date-parsing

I have string "6:00 AM" i want to convert this string to seconds or milliseconds in java.
Please suggest me standard way to convert this.

seconds from midnight "00:00 am"

Comment: from "00 00 am"  midnight

Comment: Assuming you have Java 8, I would use the `LocalTime` class, which has a `parse` method and a `toSecondOfDay` method.  If you have Java 7 or below, you might want to get your hands on the Joda library.

Comment: sorry but i am currently using java 7

Comment: Are you allowed to use Joda?

Comment: my question is not useful? why down vote ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the amount of seconds passed from the midnight with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389500/how-can-i-find-the-amount-of-seconds-passed-from-the-midnight-with-java)

Comment: @SameerKazi My guess is that the down vote is due to you posting a duplicate question instead of bothering to read the hundreds of existing Questions and Answers on this topic.

Comment: @SameerKazi Yes, you can delete your own question. But don't do so in this case. The answer by MadProgrammer is too good to lose. In only wish he or she had placed that answer on one of the original Questions rather than a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Java 7

Convert the `String` to a `Date`...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
TimeZone gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
sdf.setTimeZone(gmt);
Date date = sdf.parse("6:00 am");
```

Because there is no date information, this will be the milliseconds since the epoch + your time.

Convert the `Date` to seconds

```
long seconds = date.getTime() / 1000;
System.out.println(seconds);
```

Which outputs `21600` seconds, 360 minutes or 6 hours

## Java 8

Something more like...

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse("6:00 AM", 
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m a"));
System.out.println(lt.toSecondOfDay());
```

...for example...

## JodaTime

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse("6:00 am", 
                new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().
                                appendHourOfDay(1).
                                appendLiteral(":").
                                appendMinuteOfHour(1).
                                appendLiteral(" ").
                                appendHalfdayOfDayText().toFormatter());
LocalTime midnight = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
Duration duration = new Duration(midnight.toDateTimeToday(), lt.toDateTimeToday());
System.out.println(duration.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds());
```

Comment: Great answer! **To future visitors:** The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

*Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.*

Answer (score 1):

[Joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html) is a good choice when you need to deal with date time calculation.

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("K:mm a");
DateTime end = fmt.parseDateTime("6:00 AM");
DateTime start = fmt.parseDateTime("00:00 AM");
Interval interval = new Interval(start,end);
long millSec = interval.toDurationMillis();
long second = interval.toDuration().getStandardSeconds();
```

Comment: What version of Joda-Time are you using?  I tried using 2.4 and 2.7 but both give me an error for `Interval interval = new Interval(start,end);`